# Disguise reload as new post event, without parent dispaying "This page cannot be refreshed without resending information" message

Tags: javascript, events, popup, reload

I have a parent site with forms and I have links which open a popup via `open.window`.

I want to reload the parent site with `opener.location.reload()` in the Jquery `.unload event`. This works fine until the user submits the form on the parent site and then closes the popup. I get the usual "This page cannot be refreshed without resending information" message.

I tried to add some GET parameter to the `opener.location.href`, which had no effect.

Can I somehow simulate a post submit with the `opener.location.reload()` event, or is there an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
```

This will do a GET of the opening page, back to itself.

Comment: Yes i have tried that changes nothing. Even with an additional GET parameter.

Comment: After few tests i think this should work in the most cases. I use SAP BSP and had to rewrite parts of the opener.location.href.